# Flexbox doesn't respect overflow-x: hidden on body (Safari / iOS webkit)

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

Normally, setting `overflow-x: hidden` on the body should mean that the entire page never scrolls.

But in MacOS Safari, and iOS webkit (Safari, Chrome etc), if nested *flexbox* elements overflow the body, `overflow-x: hidden` is not respected.

Open the following in Chrome / Firefox and it works fine.

**Open in Safari or iOS webkit, and it scrolls.**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdPbGN

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main class="flex">
    <aside class="sidebar">
      
    </aside>
    <section class="content">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple fix, though not obvious if you assume overflow-x: hidden should *always* stop a parent scrolling when any of it's children / grandchildren overflow.

The fix is to put `overflow-x: hidden` on the **same element** as `display: flex`.

I feel this is a bug in Safari / iOS webkit. Curious if others agree.